# How do I connect to external WIFI router from the docker container running in the macvlan?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, docker, vlan

**What do I want to get:**

I want to be able to connect to multiple wireless routers from a single physical machine (Laptop), I can't change their configuration, so they have to be running DHCP server on their part. The only thing I can do is configure the laptop as I want. as far as I researched MACVLANs are the way to go for connecting to multiple networks from a single physical machine.

---

The network topology needs to be dynamic, so new devices can join/disconnect at runtime.

---

My plan is to write the script that runs on the host and spins up a container each time a new device connects as well as puts the created container in the new macvlan. I can achieve this by having one free container all the time that looks for new WIFI routers to connect, once connected it sends the signal to the host machine so that host can create a new macvlan and spin up a new container.

**What do I already have:**

1. I have Ubuntu 18.04 running on Virtual Box, That has network settings: Premiscouse mode on and NAT adaptor enabled
2. There is a docker host running on Ubuntu with one container (alpine distribution).

I have followed [this blog post](https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/05/29/docker-macvlan-and-ipvlan-network-plugins/). 
so I have a docker container, running on a macvlan that I can ping from the Ubuntu host.

> Here is the output of docker network inspect 92360e976cfd:

```
[
{
    "Name": "pub_net",
    "Id": "92360e976cfde6fa9b2aa85b7dfe50a8ebf6e9dbec0c2ad4025de684d388a24c",
    "Created": "2020-04-12T23:37:58.441847504+04:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "macvlan",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "10.0.2.15/24",
                "Gateway": "10.0.2.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "e222393f1f6215999bc26626acf0015071e05448763f4155dac4099b86df9796": {
            "Name": "modest_turing",
            "EndpointID": "0da3d13d8c685b32d421433d34fc6e887e69e55a929df6c1f610cfdf75678590",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:03",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.3/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "parent": "enp0s3"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
```

]

> docker network ls:

```
9979b3a1a4d1        bridge              bridge              local
6331af1d0644        host                host                local
b25f38901cf1        none                null                local
92360e976cfd        pub_net             macvlan             local
```

### The question:

How do I let containers running on the host to connect to WiFi networks?

Comment: You mention a VBox, so what is the host OS?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, host OS is Windows 10.

Comment: You're adding two difficult things: handling a wireless interface from the host to the VM, and then wanting to bridge WIFI (yes, don't be blinded, MACVLAN is a special form of bridging). WIFI requires 4 addresses mode (instead of 3) when bridged: see https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header. You can try and use IPVLAN instead, which leaves only *one* MAC visible outside. But this usually prevents DHCP to work correctly.

Comment: what I am planning to do is downloading the docker image on laptop and running is from the docker host installed on Laptop. 
If I do it with IPVLANS how can routers connect to it? they need a unique mac address.